# When installing dlib in anaconda it says unsatisfiable error

Tags: anaconda, dlib

[image]

I'm trying to install dlib library in anaconda python. It says unsatisfiable error.

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

-dlib -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*']
  -dlib -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0']

Your python: python=3.7

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Images of text should either be replaced by the text, or augmented with the text. Images of text are not searchable, nor are they accessible. Please [edit] the question and include the error message as text and use the provided formatting tools to format it.

Comment: Corrected image URL formatting.